# How can we define tensor product of random variable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, tensor-products

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and $(\tilde\Omega, \tilde{\mathcal F},\mathbb Q)$ two probability space. Let $X$ a random variable on $\Omega $ and $Y$ a random variable on $\tilde{\Omega }$.

**Q1)** By the way, should I say that $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F)$, on $(\mathcal W,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ or just $\Omega $ is enough ? I think I should precise $(\Omega ,\mathcal F)$ but depending on the context, to say $\Omega $ should be fine, no ?

**Q2)** Does all those "tensor product" define a random variable on $(\Omega \times \tilde\Omega , \mathcal F\otimes \tilde{\mathcal F}, \mathbb P\otimes \mathbb Q)$ ?

1) $X\otimes Y= X+Y$ i.e. $(X\otimes Y)(\omega ,\tilde \omega)=X(\omega )+Y( \tilde \omega )$

2) $X\otimes Y=XY$ i.e. $(X\otimes Y)(\omega ,\tilde \omega)=X(\omega )Y( \tilde \omega )$

3) $X\otimes Y=(X,Y)$ i.e. $(X\otimes Y)(\omega ,\tilde \omega)=(X(\omega ),Y( \tilde \omega ))$,

or I have to be careful ?

I would say that 1) is not, 3) it is, but for 2) I have doubt. In one hand, $\mathbb P\otimes \mathbb Q(A\times B)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb Q(B)$, but in the other hand, I don't see how to prove that $(X\otimes Y)^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F\otimes \tilde{\mathcal F}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concreteness, I will sometimes write $\Omega$ instead of $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ (similarly for $\overline{\Omega}$), and assume that $X,Y$ are $\mathbb{R}$-valued and also that, in $(3)$, you intend to give $\mathbb{R}^2$ the product $\sigma$-algebra arising from the one you gave to $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. Borel or Lebesgue). I will also write $\otimes_i$ for the "tensor product" appearing in the $i$-th point.

This boils down to seeing that the maps are measurable. Recall that the definition of the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega \otimes \overline{\Omega}$ is essentially defined by insisting only that the projection maps $p_1: \Omega \otimes \overline{\Omega} \to \Omega$ and $p_2:\Omega \otimes \overline{\Omega} \to \overline{\Omega}$ are measurable.

First, we can "lift" $X$ and $Y$ to random variables on $\Omega \otimes \overline{\Omega}$ by defining $\tilde{X} = X \circ p_1$ and $\tilde{Y} = Y \circ p_2$. As a composition of measurable maps, these are measurable. It immediately follows that $X \otimes_1 Y = \tilde{X} + \tilde{Y}$ and $X \otimes_2 Y = \tilde{X} \cdot \tilde{Y}$ are measurable since pointwise sums and products of measurable maps are measurable.

For $(3)$, recall that a map $f: \Omega_3 \to \Omega_1 \otimes \Omega_2$ into a product of two measurable spaces is measurable if and only if it's components $f \circ \pi_1$ and $f \circ \pi_2$ are measurable. In our case, this says $X \otimes_3 Y : \Omega \otimes \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if $\tilde{X} = X \otimes_3 Y \circ \pi_1$ and $\tilde{Y} = X \otimes_3 Y \circ \pi_2$ are measurable. This we already know, so all three "tensor products" define random variables on the product space.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. So at the end, to denote $X(\omega )+Y(\omega ')=X\otimes Y(\omega ,\omega ')$, it's not really an abuse of notation, right ? (I thought this notation was always for $X\otimes Y(\omega ,\omega ')=(X(\omega ),Y(\omega '))$.

Comment: If you define it like this then it isn't. The problem is that this doesn't give the other properties you'd expect the tensor product to have. The usual definition of the tensor product of random variables is $(2)$ since this definition has nice behaviour with respect to integrability properties. If you know enough of these things, e.g. you hope that the tensor product you write down gives that $L^2(\Omega \otimes \overline{\Omega}) \simeq L^2(\Omega) \otimes L^2(\overline{\Omega})$ where the tensor product on the right hand side is of Hilbert spaces. For that you want $(2)$.